# Multiindex Dataframe Merge Columns together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in the following format:

```
                                    2022-07-04                             2022-07-11
                                    27          27.1        27.2           28          28.1         28.2
index      id           employee                
1          1234565      Max         project1    customer1   in progress    project1    customer1    in progress
                                    project2    customer2   in progress    project2    customer2    in progress
```

What I want to achieve is the following format:

```
                                    2022-07-04                          2022-07-11
                                    27                                  28          
index      id           employee                
1          1234565      Max         project1, customer1, in progress    project1, customer1, in progress
                                    project2, customer2, in progress    project2, customer2, in progress
```

So I have a multilevel Index, and I want to merge the columns to one column, which are under the Top Level column. So for example under the top level '2022-07-04' I have three columns (27, 27.1, 27.2) and I want to merge these 3 columns to one column, and the same for the next date (2022-07-11) and so on... The size is always 3 columns, so below top level are always 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for columns names by levels, in second remove values after `.` and use custom lambda function for `join`:

```
c1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1).str.split('.').str[0]
c2 = df.columns.get_level_values(0)

df = df.groupby([c2, c1], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.agg(', '.join, axis=1))
print (df)
                                              2022-07-04  \
                                                      27   
index id      employee                                     
1     1234565 Max       project1, customer1, in progress   
              Max       project2, customer2, in progress   

                                              2022-07-11  
                                                      28  
index id      employee                                    
1     1234565 Max       project1, customer1, in progress  
              Max       project2, customer2, in progress
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to add the "27" and "28" to c1, because right now because there is no comma in it, there are seen as NaN values. So the result of c1 is: Index([ nan, '27'', '27',  nan, '28', '28',...]
As a result, the first entry is not merged, only the second and third entry.

Comment: @Treemaster how working `c1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1). astype('str').str.split('.').str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard for me to understand the datastructure. I guess you could create a new array in the shape which you want, say

```
newArray = np.zeros((5,2),dtype = object)
```

and then go through the array with a for-loop. And for each column set the newArray-column to the one of the original array, except at column 4 and 5, where you can use sth like np.append or str.join to link the remaining entries together.

Comment: It is called MultiIndex.